# How do I create a method that allows 2 players to fight each other in Php/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on a turn based multiplayer game using php and ajax. The features allow players to log into the game using user info, and select game modes which allows them to either play against AI or opponents. Each user can select a character from a list, and this function has already been completed. I would like to create a search function so that a player could search and battle another player, something similar to chess. However, at the moment I would like for the player to enter another users username in order for the search to take place. I have searched open source to find a method to creating a search function, but the current function I found breaks my code. Here is my current mode codes:

```
// Define Mode
if (isset($_GET['mode'])) {
    $mode = $secure->clean($_GET['mode']);
} else {
    $mode = '';
}
if ($mode == 'selection') {

    $page_title .=' > Character Selection';
    $page_titles .= ' Character Selection - Power Bond';

}
else if ($mode == 'search') {


if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
    $type = $secure->clean($_GET['type']);
} else {
    $type = '';
}

    if ($type == 'private') { 
        if (isset($_POST['pbsubmit']))  {
             $name = $secure->clean($_POST['name']);


        }
    }


}
```

Now here is my ajax. The function I found was for checking the match in order to find the username. That function breaks my game.

```
//Check the match.
if (isset($_POST['f']) && $_POST['f'] == 'checkMatch')  {
$checkMatch = $db->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE `id` = '".$account['id']."'");
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($checkMatch)) {
        $status = $info['status'];
        $gameid = $info['gameid'];
    }

$getGame = $db->fetch("SELECT * FROM Games WHERE `gameid` = '$gameid'");

        $status = $info['status'];
        $gameid = $info['gameid'];

if(!$getGame = 'NULL') {
    $data = 'testaeta';
} else {
    $data = '<h1> Who do you want to battle against? </h1>
<br />
<form action="" method="post" id="form-pb" name="pb" target="_self">
USERNAME:<input name="name" type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" />

<input name="pbsubmit" type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
<a class="goback" href="#">Cancel</a>';
}

echo $data;

}`
```

Here is my Javascripit:

```
`var match = null;
function popUp(what){
if(!what) errorMessage('Error: params', 'params', 'none');
switch(what){
    case 'search':
        preLoad('Loading please wait . . .');
        $('#main_container').prepend('<div id="popup"><div class="opacity"></div><div class="search"></div></div>');
        $('.search').load('./?page=game&mode=search&type=private', function(){
            $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){
                $('#preloader').remove();
            });         
        });
    break;
    case 'match':
        $.ajax({
            url : _path + "/core/ajax.php",
            type : 'POST',
            data : { f: 'checkMatch'},
            dataType : 'text',
            success :  function(data) {
                if(data){
                    $('#main_container').prepend(data);
                    match = setInterval(function(){
                        if(!$('.search').length){
                            $('#main_container').prepend('<div id="popup"><div class="opacity"></div><div class="search"></div></div>');
                        }
                        $('.search').load('./?page=game&mode=search&type=private', function(){

                            var meta = $('#stopMe').attr('content');
                            if(meta){
                                meta = meta.split("URL="), meta = meta[1];
                                window.location = meta;                                             
                            }

                        });                                     
                    },1000);
                }
            }
        });
    break;
    case 'submit':
        $.post('./?page=game&mode=search&type=private', $("#form-pb").serialize(), function(data){
            var $response=$(data);
            var error = $response.filter('h3').text();
            $('.search').html(data);                
            if(!error){
                match = setInterval(function(){
                if(!$('.search').length){
                    $('#main_container').prepend('<div id="popup"><div class="opacity"></div><div class="search"></div></div>');
                }
                $('.search').load('./?page=game&mode=search&type=private', function(){
                    var meta = $('#stopMe').attr('content');                                var meta = $('#stopMe').attr('content');
                    if(meta){
                        meta = meta.split("URL="), meta = meta[1];
                        window.location = meta;                                         
                    }                           
                });                             
                },1000);                    
            }
        });         
    break;
}
}
```

`
Aside from mysql, those are my main focuses on allowing this to work. Does anyone have a solution on how I could fix this problem? Also, I would like an open source example if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to search an already coded search solution, generally this is very specific to your application and not complicated.

Look for an autocompletion tool ([jQuery provide it](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)), a way to get secure data (GET or POST but check it) and a search method: LIKE %...% (simple) or [MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) (More complete)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a match making system. You could create a table in mysql and name it something like active battles. It then takes user A's info and matches it with user B, putting them inside a battle. I think you could also make a table for the battles actions. That table shows what the users do while in a battle.